# gvisCalendar width in flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, googlevis, flexdashboard

I created a calendar heatmap with GoogleVis in flexdashboard. But the plot's width is only half of the page. I want to strech the plot to full-width.

This is my data:

```
    head(test)
           num_of_clients
1996-07-18             12
1996-07-19             21
1996-07-20             19
1996-07-22             20
1996-07-23             28
1996-07-24             11
```

This is my code:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
require(googleVis)

Cal <- gvisCalendar(test, 
                    datevar="DOTVORANJE", 
                    numvar="num_of_clients",
                    options=list(
                      width=900,
                      calendar="{yearLabel: { fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                               fontSize: 32, color: '#1A8763', bold: true},
                               cellSize: 10,
                               cellColor: { stroke: 'red', strokeOpacity: 0.2 },
                               focusedCellColor: {stroke:'red'}}")
)

print(Cal)
````

The output I get is the image below

[image]

Addendum:

I initially tried to render the plot without the 'width=900' parametar, nevertheless the plot does not fill the container entirely.

Further, I tried to play with the 'cellSize' parametar, which increases the actual width of the plot, but in that case I lose control over the plot height. For instance, if I increase the container area Row{data-height=1500}, the plot again does not fill it.

Any other ideas how I can get full-width of the page with the calendar?

Many thanks!

Comment: Remove `width=900`, then it should default to "width of the containing element". https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

Comment: That's what I did initially. But its not filling the container. I also tried with the 'cellSize' parameter, which is increasing the plot in width, but than I am unable to show the full height.

Comment: Great, worth editing your post with what you have tried so far and failed.